# display bootstrap popover with right-to-left languages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, right-to-left, bootstrap-popover

I am using [bootstrap 3.3.5](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

I have a test page in which the user can switch between a left-to-right language (English, French, German, etc.) to a right-to-left language (Arabic, Hebrew, etc.).

The issue that I have is that the [bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) does not display correctly under the right-to-left language.

If the user is viewing the page in a right-to-left language, then I pull in the rtl bootstrap css page, otherwise the left-to-right css page is used.

For example, the right-to-left bootstrap css is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..../assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css">
```

The left-to-right bootstrap css is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..../assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Here is a visual display of the popover under the left-to-right language:

[image]

Here is a visual display of the popover under the right-to-language, which is not displaying correctly (the arrow and position of the popover is still as if using a left-to-right language/css):

[image]

Please ignore the contents of the right-to-left popover, as I have not yet placed in the translation files/links.

I have searched SO & Google for this, but I could not locate a reference to this issue. **Does anyone have a suggestion to correct this issue?**

Comment: you can see the difference in rendered(obviously via inspecting) css property for both and compare in difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that this will fix the popover issue you are expeiencing.

In your rtl css place this code:

```
.popover {
    direction: rtl;
    -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

The above code will flip the entire popover.

Next, you will need to add the following code right under the above mentioned popover css class:

```
.popover-title {
    -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

.popover-content {
    -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

the above code will then flip back the popover title and body.

This will mean that the popover arrow is correctly positioned **and** the text in the popover is also displayed correctly - in this case rtl.

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the css file

```
#your_id{
    direction: rtl;
}
```

it should work

Comment: Dvoka, thanks for the suggestion, but this does not work. This issue is occuring for all the popovers, not just the one - so I assuming that the issue is css related.

Comment: what do you mean for all the popovers? have you tried to change the css to be no #id{} and to be .class{}?

Comment: Dvoka, yes I have tried that - no change to the popovers. This occuring to all the popovers in the test site under the rtl languages.