# How to make the content text "rtl" in popover button via bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I have a pop hover button. I want to make it's text `RTL`. How can I do it?

```
<button
    type                = "button"
    class               = "btn btn-success btn-xs pop"
    data-container      = "body"
    data-toggle         = "popover"
    data-placement      = "right"
    data-content        = "hello world"
    data-original-title = ""
    title               = "">help</button>
```

Comment: using `direction: rtl;` [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp)

Comment: How should I use it. Where?

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
style="direction:rtl;"


<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pop" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"  data-content="hello world"
  data-original-title="" title="" style="direction:rtl;" >
```

Comment: Please share a picture of the button

Comment: I added a picture in question.

Answer (score 0):

> A paragraph with a right-to-left direction:
>
> `<p dir="rtl">Write this text right-to-left!</p>`

For your case, and as documented on bootstrap, you have the option to change the popover tempate via the attribute data-template

```
<div class="popover" role="tooltip" direction="rtl">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
    <div class="popover-content"></div>
</div>
```

In your code, add this attribute and set the direction to `rtl` both in title and body

```
<button data-template='<div class="popover" role="tooltip" dir="rtl"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>' ...>
    Help
<button>
```

[HTML rtl attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp)

[bootstrap popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

Comment: It does not work. I want to make the content of data-content rtl

Comment: <button   type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pop" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"  data-content=" <p dir='rtl'>   contents</p>"
  data-original-title="" title="" data-dir="rtl">
    help
    </button>

Comment: I have also tested above code but it writes the <p> tag in content

Answer (score 0):

try using css, like so

```
.your-class-name{
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Read the complete reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To all folks ending up here, in order to change direction or style text inside bootstrap's tooltip you can enable the HTML rendering inside tooltip using `data-html="true"` and then adding preferred HTML tags and attributes. Checkout example below:

**Step 1 - Displaying plain text in tooltip:**

```
<i class="bi bi-x-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="name=درود"></i>
```

**Step 2 - Creating the desired HTML to show in the tooltip:**

```
<p dir='rtl'><strong>name<strong>=درود</p>
```

**Step 3 - Displaying text with direction and bold style:**

```
<i class="bi bi-x-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" title="&lt;p dir='ltr'&gt;<strong>name<strong>=درود&lt;/p&gt;"></i>
```

*- There are also other possible solutions such as editing the CSS class of popover or tooltip, such as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32281462/8551764).*